Run UNIT TEST automatically from NeoVim
Still working on my neovim configuration.
I use Google test to write my unit tests. Which means that all the unit test begin with TEST(<groupName>, <testName>). This little script see if the cursor is inside a test sets a break point and then runs the test application for that test.
This is useful as I can run my make test from inside neovim that builds and runs the test. If any of the unit tests fail then the error is in the QuickFix list which allows me to jump to the failing test in a couple of key strokes and I can now invoke the test directly.
Any pointers on Bad Lua or bad usage of neovim functions and better ways appreciated.
  -- Set the Key <leader>du to run this command
  -- Run all the unit tests
  vim.cmd.DapRunUnitTests = function() vim.cmd.DapRunUnitTestCode({})     end

  -- Set the Key <leader>dt to run this command
  -- Run the unit test that the cursor is over.
  vim.cmd.DapRunOneTests  = function()
      -- Search backwards for a line that marks the begining of the TEST.
      local lineNo = vim.fn.search('TEST(', 'bn')
      if (lineNo == 0) then
          return
      end

      -- Extract the name of the test
      local text = vim.fn.getline(lineNo)
      local res = { string.match(text, "(%w+)%((%w+), (%w+)%)") }

      if (#res == 3 and res[1] == 'TEST') then
          -- Set a breakpoint at the current line
          -- Then run the unit test code specifying the unit test to run.
          require('dap').set_breakpoint()
          vim.cmd.DapRunUnitTestCode({'---gtest_filter=' .. res[2] .. '.' .. res[3]})
      end
  end

  -- Function that runs the unit tests.
  vim.cmd.DapRunUnitTestCode = function(args)

      -- Use make to get runtime environment need to run the
      -- unit test application.
      local handle = assert(io.popen('make neovimruntime', 'r'))
      local output = handle:read('*a')
      io.close(handle)

      -- Set the runtime environment.
      -- Need to modify for non MAC environments.
      require('posix').setenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH', output)

      -- Set up the config needed.
      local config = {
          name = 'Launch',
          type = 'lldb',
          request = 'launch',
          program = 'test/coverage/unittest.prog',
          cwd = '${workspaceFolder}',
          stopOnEntry = false,
          args = args,
      }

      -- Start the debug seasion.
      require('dap').run(config)
  end


auto shortcuts
  -- Set the Key <leader>du to run this command

There's a couple of comments in this standard format.
Hopefully a Makefile or other script
reads them to generate .vimrc map_mode config lines.
Consider putting valid .vimrc syntax in these comments,
so a trivial awk one-liner can generate a config file.
alias
I guess you found
DapRunUnitTests a more convenient spelling than
DapRunUnitTestCode?
Ok.
Not sure why it's a win,
given that it's bound to a keyboard shortcut.
Whatever.
Or maybe you needed a line of source just to help
with autogenerating a .vimrc?
UX
  vim.cmd.DapRunOneTests  = function()
      ...
      if (lineNo == 0) then
          return

Maybe beep?
Or display some brief error indication?
Then the user will know that this ran, there's no config mixup,
the trouble stems instead from the buffer content.
regex
  local res = { string.match(text, "(%w+)%((%w+), (%w+)%)") }

Rather than testing res[1], putting the literal
in the regex would be simpler and more intuitive:
                               ... "TEST%((%w+), (%w+)%)") }

Also, I'm sure your whitespace is always immaculate.
But when I am authoring code, sometimes the spacing
is a bit sloppy until a prettyprinter cleans it up.
You might prefer to accept greater variation in whitespace:
                               ... "TEST%((%w+),%s*(%w+)%)") }

Your subsequent use of res[2] and res[3] is a little
more obscure than necessary.
Consider assigning them to temp variables that have meaningful names.
nit, comment typos: "needed to run"
and "non Mac environments".
I'm afraid that when I see "MAC" I think of comms layer 2
and IEEE-assigned 48-bit identifiers.
common path support
      require('posix').setenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH', output)

Definitely this works for you.
And you're running the test code as a child of vim, good.
Me? I tend to run within several environments:

editor
IDE
bash

The DapRunUnitTestCode function seems pretty generic across all those.
So I'm sad that this logic is not e.g. packaged up in a bash script
which vim calls.
Alternatively, maybe this function would like to write a dot file
which bash can conveniently source?

Hopefully a Makefile or other script reads them to generate .vimrc map_mode config lines. I am trying to write everything in lua to match what I see other people doing in neovim. I have translated all my .vimrc into lua scripts etc. Is that not the prefered new trick?

Maybe beep? Or display some brief error indication? Yes. That's a good idea. How?

Me? I tend to run within several environments: Me to. :-) Though not IDE (as vim is my IDE and editor) :-). It works in bash already natively as everything is connected via the Makefile to do everything correctly. Just trying to get my vim (neovim) and make file environment to interact nicely here.
